# Inserting record using DataAdapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
DatasetTableAdapters.CustomerDataAdapter customerData = new DatasetTableAdapters.CustomerDataAdapter();

customerData.insertQuery("Value1", "Value");
```

The record is not being inserted into the Database Why? I am using Dataset Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this maybe?

```
    DatasetTableAdapters.CustomerDataAdapter customerData = new DatasetTableAdapters.CustomerDataAdapter();

    //make instance of the applicable customerDataTable here

    customerData.Fill(customerDataTable);
    customerDataTable.Rows.Add("Value1", "Value");//<-you could also add the values directly to your dataset here instead of the datatable

    customerData.Update(customerDataTable);
```

I am using this method in a winforms app. Maybe you could just edit it to suit your needs as applicable?

Comment: Instead of the .Update method, you could try using your .insertQuery and see if that works too. But because a new row is added to the datatable, the update automatically does insert first as it does not edit a row in the dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the  `.Insert` method on the table adaptor instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: it is the .Insert method.  i have just changed the name.

Comment: @Mussarant - How did you change the name?

Comment: when i generate the insert query from Dataset desiger at that time.

Comment: Are you getting any type of exception?

Comment: no i am not just cant see the data which i am inserting to be appeared into the database file